# Is it safe to cache DatastoreService object in static field? (GAE Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a code snippet:

```
private static DatastoreService _db;

public static DatastoreService db() throws IOException
{
    if(_db==null) _db = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    return _db;
}
```

Is this safe approach? I cached the DatastoreService object statically and re-used over a single servlet execution. However, I have no sure about the servlet disposes after a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for that kind of initialization code would be in your `init()` method that you should override in your servlet. There is also a corresponding `destroy()` method if you need to do any cleanup. See [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/05/14/java_webserver.html) and [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch03_03.htm).